# Is this C++0x optimization legal?

Tags: c++, c++11

Is it legal for a C++0x compiler to optimize

```
int func(int&& a){
    a = 3;
    return a;
}
```

to

```
int func(int&& a){
    return 3;
}
```

?
(or for another POD)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not like that *per se*, because the function must modify the variable `a` to be equivalent. That said, after inlining and a bit of trivial optimization the result will be the same:

```
int x = func(5);

// pseudo-inlined:
int __temp = 5; // the temporary created by binding 5 to int&&
__temp = 3; // a = 3;
int x = __temp; // return a;

// constant propagation:
int __temp = 5;
__temp = 3;
int x = 3;

// dead-code elimination:
int x = 3;
```

Note the result is the same as if you used the second definition of `func` and inlined, only because the temporary variable wasn't used. This shows that the two functions aren't equivalent in general:

```
int modifyme = 100;
int x = func(std::move(modifyme));

// modifyme must be 3, second function definition wouldn't do that
```

Comment: I would have thought that reading the value of an object after moving it is UB.  Is that not the case?

Comment: Thought so too - I'd be extremely surprised if this wasn't the case, although for primitive types just leaving the value alone is the cheapest option obviously (for complex types they can't do that though I'd think?)

Comment: My thoughts were also that it would be UB, at least for PODs (without destructors). For non-PODs they of course have to be changed so all pointers can be set to 0 so the destructor won't do anything...

Comment: Compilers are free to exploit undefined behaviour - programmers are not.

Comment: @GMan: I'm referring to reading the value of modifyme after the call to the function.  You say it must be 3.  This implies that you can read it's value and expect a defined result.

Comment: @Benjamin: `std::move(modifyme)` is just shorthand for `static_cast<int&&>(modifyme)`, and I don't see anything in the standard that suggests undefined behavior arises from reading from that, though I'm less read in these regards. It just changes the value category, and is still a regular variable, in my understanding.

Comment: The thing I wanted to do is something like if you have a struct A { int a[10000]; }. Then I want to "transfer the ownership" of it to a function with A&&, so it can use optimizations on it, like it can do with a local struct A, i.e. not store the values in the array if it isn't needed. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Emil: Well you should have asked your real question in the question area. :) I'm not sure what optimizations you're talking about; do you mean to get rid of aliasing?

Comment: I think I will start a new question.

Comment: @Benjamin: my copy of the standard says (after rv is moved from) `rv remains a valid object. Its state is unspecified`  I can't find anything on PODs, but I doubt they're UB given the prev statement.

Comment: @Mooing: That's just the requirements for the standard library. That doesn't say it's *necessarily* unspecified to everyone, just that as far as the standard library is concerned, it no longer cares what state it's in. In other words, there are no requirements an object must fulfill after being moved from.

Comment: @GMan: § 5.17.3 `If the left operand is not of class type, the expression is implicitly converted (Clause 4) to the cv-unqualified
type of the left operand.`  Which would remove the &&.

Comment: Can you provide a link as to why the optimization cannot be applied? My guess is that it would be based on the assumption that after moving the *moved* object is left in an undefined *destroyable* state, and leaving it exactly as it is would comply with that contract. And here I am not talking about a fundamental type, but rather a user defined type for which the compiler has visibility into the move constructor, copy constructor and whatever other code is used inside `func` (even if the function `func` itself is not inlined)

Comment: @David: Is that to me? I'm afraid I don't understand the concern. "after moving the moved object is left in an undefined destroyable state" I don't see anything in the standard that says a moved object is in such a state. What I do see is the standard library requiring this to be true *at a minimum*.

Comment: @David: GMan says it can be applied, unless that POD type is also named, in which case it must assign to `a` as well (`return a=3`).  However, it may be the case that that assignment _also_ gets optimized out.