# string returned by function

Tags: c#, string

If I write the following code :

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpy(myObj.GetString()))
{
  var myString  = myObj.GetString() + myObj.GetString();
}
```

My function GetString() will be called 3 times, then it can execute some complex code 3times. Is there a simpler way than :

```
var firstString = myObj.GetString();
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpy(firstString))
{
  var myString  = firstString  + firstString;
}
```

to have only one execution of the code in GetString() ?

Comment: Why are you adding two null-or-empty strings?  Or is this just a dodgy example?  Anyway in the general case I think your second code is the best way of avoiding the evaluation of GetString() multiple times.

Comment: Does the string change based on the values in myObj?  Or is it a simple get?  Will it ever change once's it's created?

Comment: whats wrong with the second snippet?

Comment: as admirable as the first one unless I'm missing something

Comment: @James Gaunt no it is just a dodgy example, I don't have enough imagination,sorry ...

Comment: @tahir: I think you meant if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstString))

Comment: @James Michael Hare it can change in the application but not in the method. Actually I'm just wonderring if there is a smart cache mechanism that will say "oh I have already evaluated this string, I will return the known value", or c# is not so smart and I will have to implement a cache myself (a private field refreshed when needed) ?

Comment: The second snippet is as good an answer as anyone will be able to give to the very general case you've given. Give us some actual code and it might be possible to come up with something more specific.

Comment: @James Gaunt fixed the missing "!" ...

Comment: @tahir If your GetString() is simple enough then the compiler will *probably* inline the calls and make any appropriate optimizations at the memory model level. If performance is a problem (after performance profiling!) then it's probably better to implement your own caching, especially if your GetString pushes around a lot of internal state.

Comment: I'm not sure if the C# compiler is smart enough to recognize when your GetString() is a pure method with no side-effect. What if your GetString is returning a random string? What if it's writing into a log every time it's called? In those cases it's up to you to decide if you want to call it twice or just once and save the result of the first call (since calling it twice has side-effects, calling it twice will not be the same thing as calling it once and caching the result).

Comment: @tahir: So are you saying the string changes on demand?  That is, the application controls when it changes?  Or does it change when the application changes some other internal state?  Perhaps if you showed us your class...

Comment: @James Michael Hare Actually there is no particular case to show, I write the seconde piece of code very often, and I was wondering if it was useless as C# may handle the optim itself. But with the comment of paolo just above, I see that if it was handled by c#, it would not be a good idea...

Comment: @tahir: yes, basically, if GetString() just returned a field, it's theoretically possible the CLR could inline that -- in which case would be better as a property anyway -- but if there's any logic such a thing would be undesirable.

Comment: @paolo I saw [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153710/is-this-c0x-optimization-legal/7153810#7153810) yesterday. It's for C++0x but I think you get the idea of the kind of optimizations that can effectively answer these questions of purity. I'm not sure if such things are actually done by the C# compiler or the JIT compiler.

Comment: @James Michael Hare why is a property better in this case ? for optim or to write clean code ?

Comment: @Brian Gordon: not by the C# compiler, it seems. I created a console application with the first call in tahir's example, with a GetString() method that just returns a constant string, compiled it and de-compiled it with ILSpy: GetString() was still called twice.

Comment: @paolo Yeah I agree with you; the CIL has GetString being called twice. Inlining must be done by the jitter because there's no way that the platform developers missed such an obvious optimization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You COULD make it more complex and have an IsChanged bool value, and if anything in the object changes set IsChanged to true and then rebuild the string, else return the last string built, but then you'd need to add synchronization and it probably wouldn't be worth the cost.

So, the long and the short is that the 2nd case is generally the best case.  It's simple and straightforward and efficient.

**UPDATE**: It's hard to tell what the update scenario is here.  So let's look at several.

1). If you are only updating the string on demand from the application, and that string is created using some complex method, just have a new update method and then return the current string as a property.  Then, you can just query the MyString property and it will be a simple return.

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public string MyString { get; private set; }

    public void UpdateString(...)
    {
       // DO YOUR COMPLEX LOGIC

       MyString = ... new value ...
    }
}
```

2). Or, if it's just a simple string with no complex logic, you could have the application responsible for creating and assigning it:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public string MyString { get; set; }
}

...

myObj.MyString = SomeComplexLogicToBuildString();
```

But as I said, that's only if the string representation is independent from the state of the object.

3). If it's based on the state of the object and changes when the object state changes, you could let the string be re-created whenever something changes:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private bool _hasChanged = true;
    private string _previousString = null;


    public string MyString
    {
        get 
        {
            if (_hasChanged)
            {
                _hasChanged = false;
                _previousString = .... your complex string building logic ....
            } 

            return _previousString;
        }
    }

    public int OtherProperties
    {
        get { return _otherField; }
        set { _otherField = value; _hasChanged = true; }
    }
```

But once again, you'd probably want to synchronize this if it's multi-threaded use.

**BUT** This is all **IF** you want to cache the value so it's not rebuilt each time as a responsibility of the class itself.

Truly, your simplest and best bet is just to use your second method, and if you are using it several times in one method just set to a temporary variable and use that.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative:

```
var firstString = myObj.GetString();
var myString  = string.Concat(firstString, firstString);
```

[string.Concat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6d350wd.aspx) already manages the null case (treating it as an empty string).

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to cache the results after the first call to GetString. Then subsequent calls would use the cached copy. But the way you're doing it is fine for most cases and simpler than implementing a cache.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
public static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
        string s;
        if((s=getString())!=null) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    static string getString() 
    {
        return "hello";
    }
```

Comment: @Brian I think xwrs just put the assignment in the if statement - so it's essentially the same thing as scenario 2 in the OP's question (possibly *exactly* the same after the compiler gets done with it)

Comment: Well...other than the fact that he didn't add the two strings.  But, only one call to `getString`, which I think is the gist of the problem

Comment: @jadarnel Oh, I was bewildered by the main method and the I/O. I see now that it's just a demo wrapper with ReadLine functioning as a pause.